# Online Kanban tool with Swimlanes

Tags: task-management, kanban

I am looking for recommendations for an online Kanban tool with Swimlanes. Popular tools like Trello and Asana seem to not support this feature.

Additionally, it would be great if I could also add WIP limits. However, swimlanes are the main priority at the moment.

Comment: Gitlab and Github have this feature. In *GitLab* this is called "Boards". You can find it as a subitem of the "Issues" item in the sidebar. Maybe you can use this, with some creativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trello has only WIP limits in paid version. I suggest looking at **Teamhood**, it is free and includes both WIP limits and Swimlanes.
https://teamhood.com/use-cases/kanban-system/

[image]
https://teamhood.com/use-cases/kanban-system/

Answer (score 0):

Here is kanban tool that I found that supports swimlanes:

https://kanbantool.com/product
[image]
https://kanbantool.com/support/kanban-board/what-are-swimlanes